# display all logos on a page or map

Tags: list, dictionary, url, display, logos

I'm trying to find a way to display a list of 500+ logos from 500+ url's.
I want to make a global map of all companies with their respective logos that's i have coming from a url http://www.xxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/QOPIUS.png
The results could be like this
[Image example from medium](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*se_LrcjLYyzuR7sdvbFMjw.png)

I've tried some BI tools like Tableau or MS Report but none of them is doing the job to make a map and manually this weird.

If any ideas from there, you are welcome.
Thx.

Comment: Do you need to add text with each logo?

Comment: No. The text is the logo.

Comment: You could replace the montage command in the answer by `Wintermute 64` below with just a command to append all the images vertically, such as `convert *.jpg -append result.jpg` or if you want some space between them you can use -smush X in place of -append, such as `convert *.jpg -background white -smush 10 result.jpg` to add 10 pixels of white between the images. The main issue is if you have enough RAM to hold all the images. But since your images are logos, they are probably small enough not to overload your RAM

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Simple solution: 
If you have your URL paths in a file, just read the file line by line and download all logos. I am using bash for my example:

```
while read line; do curl -O $line; done < urls.txt
```

Once you have all your logos use imageMagick to concatenate your logos into one big jpg/png/other_file_format:

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x *.jpg map.jpg
```

For more information see imageMagick documentation:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

Comment: Thanks for your advice Wintermute 64. I'll have a look to imageMagick.